# hasMap declared transient doesnt work after object is deserialized

Tags: java, serialization

Is there anything wrong with declaring collection transient? `transient Map<String, Car> cars = new HashMap<>()` is declared in `Owner`instance that is serialized, but the `Car` class is not serialized.

When program runs for the first time `Owner` instance it creates `Car` and insert it into collection `Cars`, however when running program for second time, `Owner` is deserialized, it correctly creates `Car` instance but when adding to collection `cars.put(key, object)` it causes `NullPointerException`. Also only when running after deserialization `cars.containsKey(regNumIn)` causes exception instead of giving true or false. It seems that on second run after `Owner` is recreated the new `hashMap` is created.

Does it have to do anything with hasCode() and equals()? I havent declared those, and if they are automatically declared by Netbeans IDE, the program doesnt work at all.

Comment: The `transient` keyword in Java is used to indicate that a field should not be serialized. So after deserialization you have `null` instead of your map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not call the default constructor when deserializing the object. Therefore, your code

```java
transient Map<String, Car> cars = new HashMap<>();
```

will not be executed.

To accomplish this, you can override the `readObject` method of your class:

```
public class ... implements Serializable {
    ...
    private transient Map<String, Car> cars = new HashMap<>();
    ...
    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream)
              throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        stream.defaultReadObject();
        // Important! recreate transient field cars as empty HashMap
        this.cars = new HashMap<>();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing at all to do with Collections. "transient" tells Java that you do not want to store the fields value, so when you reload the stored object, transient fields are set to `null` (or 0, or other respective default values). Therefore, in your example code of `cars.put(key, object)`, you are essentially attempting to do `null.put(key, object)`.

`containsKey` of course fails for the same reason - you are attempting to call it on something that is `null`.

If you don't want to serialize your collection, you will have to do something like `cars = new HashMap<>()` after deserializing it.

That means the problem is also unrelated to `equals` and `hashCode`, however the information that your program 'breaks' when you have Netbeans generate them suggests that you may have other issues. Good information about `equals` and `hashCode` can be found in this related SO question:

[What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

I removed `transient` statement and I implemented Serializable interface in a `Car` class, and it works. I think the problem was that collection being `transient` was not saved after first run, and in the second run when `Owner` object was deserialized, the non-argument constructor is not called, therefore the new `cars` collection in that constructor was not created. So in the second run it was attempted to add `car` object to non existing collection.